# How to copy files in external storage in Android Q

Tags: android, android-10.0, scoped-storage

I made a app(is called A) without UI which provides some information to other clients app with AIDL.

So I want to make an UI app(is called B) for displaying A apps status and send some files to server(logs, db, etc...).

However, I'm having some problem with Scoped Storage in Android Q.

(I know about `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` but I don't want to use this trick)

I'm looking for MediaStore and SAF(Storage Access Framework) but I'm not sure which one is right and something more(what I didn't think)

Could I use MediaStore for copying DB files to external storage(actual public space for other apps)?
Could I use SAF even an App A doesn't have any UI?
(and how?)

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

Just request that legacy external storage.

It is not a trick. And quite handy for an Android 10 device. It works only on an Android 10/Q device.

> which provides some information to other clients app

In which way?

You could use a content provider for that.

Comment: I also consider about R OS. That's why I don't want to `legacy external storage`.
Thanks for replying.

Comment: You mean Android 11 api 30? Just put it in manifest as only on an Android 10 device it will be used. Then you are done for 10. For the rest a content/document provider seems the way to go.